# What's the best method to choose per my requirement to store the values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I have a grid view with some data and check boxes. Assume that my data is as follows:

```
  check box    EmpID      PayID
                123         1
               1234         1
               1234         2
```

I would like to store the corresponding `PayID` values as per the `EmpID` exists. If I select both from the check boxes available  I would like to check which `payid` belongs to which `EmpID` can any one give me an idea to implement this please.

Comment: May be using Multi value dictionary you can achieve this i think so not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way you can achieve change it as per your requirement

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] EmpIds = new int[] { 123, 1234, 1234 };
        int[] PayIds = new int[] { 1, 1, 2 };
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

        // populate dictionary
        for (int i = 0; i < EmpIds.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(EmpIds[i]))
            {
                List<int> values = new List<int>();
                dict.Add(EmpIds[i], values);
            }
            dict[EmpIds[i]].Add(PayIds[i]);
        }
        foreach (int k in dict.Keys)
        {
            foreach (int v in dict[k]) Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", k, v);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```